# PIC 18F4520 frequency and variable issues

Tags: c, pic

I am working on program with interrupt and timer to do a count down :
I am using internal oscillator (4MHz x 4 with PLL).

1 ) The frequency of the interruption is not in accordance with the frequency that I would like to reach (1000 Hz).

2) If I modify the variable int counter variable in char counter, it doesn't work.

```
 #include <xc.h>
    #include "afficheur.h"

    #include "eeprom.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "pause.h"
    #include "timer2.h"


    #define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000


    //unsigned int counter = 0; //work with bad frequency
    unsigned char counter = 0;      //doesn't work

    void interrupt isr2 (void) {            


      if (INTCONbits.TMR0IF == 1 )           
            {
    TMR0 = 6;
                INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;        

                ++counter;

            }
        }


    void timerCount(void)
    {
       LCD_init();
       initTimer();


        while(left_time!=0)
        {


            if (counter == 0)
            {
                display(left_time);

            }    

            updateTimer();
        }  
    }

    void  initTimer(void)
    {



                T0CON &= 11000011 ;      
                TMR0 = 6;

                  INTCON = 0;                    // clear the interrpt control register
                  INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 1;         // bit5 TMR0 Overflow Interrupt 
                  INTCONbits.TMR0IF = 0;        
                  INTCONbits.GIE = 1;            // bit7 global interrupt enable
    }

    void  updateTimer(void)
    {

        if (counter == 1000)  //1000 milliseconds => 1 second
        {

            counter = 0;
            left_time-=1;


        }


    }


    void  display(int time)
    {

        char str [20];

        char h_left [10];
        char m_left [10];
        char s_left [10];

        char compt [10];

        //time calculation
        sprintf(m_left, "%02d", time/60);
        sprintf(s_left, "%02d", time%60);   
        sprintf(h_left, "%02d", (time/60)/60);
        sprintf(m_left, "%02d", (time/60)%60);

        sprintf(compt,"%04d",counter);

            //**time display HH:MM:SS

        char *h_disp = h_left;
        char *m_disp = m_left;
        char *s_disp = s_left;
        char *compt_disp = compt;

        strcpy(str, h_disp);
        strcat(str, ":");
        strcat(str, m_disp);
        strcat(str, ":");

        strcat(str, s_disp);

        strcat(str, ":");
        strcat(str,compt_disp);

    //lcd rendering

        command(0xC3);
        LCD_write("Temps restant:");
        command(0x9A);
        LCD_write(str);
        //LCD_write(compt_disp);
        command(0xD4);
    }
```

I thank you in advance for your help,

Kris

Comment: The frequency of the interruption is not in accordance with the frequency that I would like to reach (1000 Hz).  OK, what is the frequency?   If it's double, load the counter with twice the value...

Comment: Thank you for the answer: it's not the double, it's more : to reach the frequency I have to put count ==12000 until count == 1000.

Comment: Char counter can't count up to 1000, it will roll over on 255, then start over. Use prescaler value 64 and compare counter == 250. You didn't include the main loop that shows how the functions are called so maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Thank you imqqmi. Your solution is OK, I have to limit the counter to 250 : I have to adapt the calculus to adapt the count value at 250 ! 
The main loop is in other part, I've just copy paste the function thats is called in the main loop.